# Where can I find information about creating 3D controls in WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, user-controls, wpf-controls

I am about to start to make the interface for a game in WPF / Silverlight. I'd like it to have a nice look all in 3 dimensions. Can you point me to some good resources, tutorials, books... on how to develop real 3D controls, like Buttons and such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Charles Petzold's Book](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/02/050710.html) on WPF 3D Applications

[WPF3D Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpf3d/)

[Codegod](http://www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/wpf-3d-animations-and-textures-AID439.aspx) tutorial on WPF 3D

12 part series on [Eric Sink's Blog](http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/index.html)

A couple of interesting resources linked [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/tims/archive/2006/02/08/527850.aspx)

More specific to controls:

[Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Continuum/3DViewControlsForWPF/) video on the topic of WPF 3D View Controls.

[2D Controls on 3D Objects](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpf3d/archive/2006/12/12/interacting-with-2d-on-3d-in-wpf.aspx).

[Thriple](http://thriple.codeplex.com/), a library of 3D controls and panels, for use in WPF applications.

[Perspective](http://www.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=perspective&ReleaseId=9161) library [use case](http://www.odewit.net/ArticleContent.aspx?id=Wpf3DControls&format=html).

Comment: Thank you, those are all great links :-) Would you have information more specific to controls?